# How do I sum up several columns with javascript and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have a table with two different columns that I would like to add up to their respective sums. Right now I just add up one of the columns, I could add up the second column by just making the same JS again but with different names for the values but that is not so pretty.
How would I do to change it so it counts the **ue** column as well as the **egen** and spit out two results, **sum** and **sum2**.

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server">Number</asp:TextBox></td>
    <td class="egen"><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox56" runat="server" Columns="1">56</asp:TextBox></td>
    <td class="ue"><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox57" runat="server" Columns="1">57</asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server">Worker</asp:TextBox></td>
    <td class="egen"><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox58" runat="server" Columns="1">58</asp:TextBox></td>
    <td class="ue"><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox59" runat="server" Columns="1">59</asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right">Sum:</td>
    <td align="center"><span id="sum"></span></td>
    <td align="center"><span id="sum2"></span></td
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is my javascript that I use to add up the values in the column **egen**.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //iterate through each td based on class / input and add keyup
    //handler to trigger sum event
    $(".egen :input").each(function () {

        $(this).keyup(function () {
            calculateSum();
        });
    });

});
function calculateSum() {

    var sum = 0;
    // iterate through each td based on class and add the values from the input
    $(".egen :input").each(function () {

        var value = $(this).val();
        // add only if the value is number
        if (!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(value);
        }
    });
    $('#sum').text(sum);
};
```

Comment: `:text` should be used.

Comment: Do youu want 2 sums like sum of .ue and sum of egen ? or is it the sum of ue and egen together?

Comment: I think the best thing I can suggest is that you use a variable for the selector and perhaps loop over an array of items [".egen",".ue"] and calculate the sum. You could also make the sum calculation a function and pass it the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target all elements in `.egen` *or* `.ue` by the following selector:

```
 $('.egen :input, .ue :input')
```

Or if you prefer:

```
$('.egen, .ue').find(':input')
```

By the way you don't need to iterate over the collection of elements to bind `keyup` listeners to them, you can bind to the entire collection immediately:

```
$('.egen :input, .ue :input').keyup(calculateSum);
```

**EDIT**

I note from the presence of `#sum` and `#sum2` that you may want to sum up the columns separately. You could do something like this:

```
$('.egen :input').keyup(function() { calculateSum('.egen'); });
$('.ue :input').keyup(function() { calculateSum('.ue'); });

function calculateSum(container) {
   var sum = 0;
   $(container).find(':input').each(function() {
       ... 
   });
}
```

And then of course set the value of `#sum` or `#sum2`, respectively. That could be acheived in a number of ways. Either you pass the id, just as we're passing the class above, or you use a class named `sum`, and have the respective `td`'s reuse the `egen` and `ue` classes. That way you could access the correct sum with `$(container+'.sum').val()`. Another solution would be to just return the sum, and setting it in your keyup listener:

```
$('.ue :input').keyup(function() {
   $('#sum2').val( calculateSum('.ue') );
});
```

Note also that your parsing could be simplified. `parseFloat` will yield `NaN` for a lot of invalid values, including empty strings and `null`, so you do not need to check your values closely before calling it. `NaN` will evaluate to false, so you could always sum by `(parsedResult || 0)`, as the result would be `0`, leaving the sum unaffected, if `parsedResult` is `NaN`.

Thus:

```
var sum = 0;
$(container).find(':input').each(function() {
   sum += (parseFloat( $(this).val() ) || 0);
});
```

Comment: Nice, had no idea you could use this syntax for parseFloat. Is that supported across all browsers?

Comment: @deed02392: There is no special `parseFloat` functionality at work here. `parseFloat` will return a `number` or `NaN`, based on its input. All browsers should have implemented that. Since `NaN` is [falsy](http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript) the operation output of `(NaN || 0)` will [default to `0`](http://seanmonstar.com/post/707078771/guard-and-default-operators). This is not a feature of `parseFloat` but of javascript.

Comment: Looks like I missed the paren on first glance, I thought you had passed it like `parseFloat( .val() || 0 );`

Answer (score 1):

changed your sum `<span>` id to its respective class_sum like

```
<span id="egen_sum"></span>
<span id="ui_sum"></span>
...
```

so that we can get this working with one function

try this

```
$('.egen :input, .ue :input').keyup(function(){
     var keyupClass= $(this).parent().hasClass('egen') ? 'egen' : 'ue';
     calculateSum(keyupClass);
 });

function calculateSum(keyupClass) {

  var sum = 0;
  $("."+ keyupClass+" :input").each(function () {

    var value = $(this).val();
    // add only if the value is number
    if (!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
        sum += parseFloat(value);
    }
  });
  $('#'+keyupClass+"_sum").text(sum);
};
```

this will work for any number of input ... just need to make sure the corresponding sum span is given the right id...

Comment: using `$(this).parent().attr('class')` assumes that the `class` attribute will never be used for anything other than the `.egen`/`.ue` distinction which may or may not be a problem presently, but is definitely a bug vulnerability. Setting `class="egen first-row"` would break the code, and just adding classes are generally assumed to be a non-breaking change. It might be preferable to use something like `keyupClass = $(this).parent().hasClass('egen') ? 'egen' : 'ue';`